# Quicker Notifications design breaks when there are ignored users

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, design, chat-profile

I just noticed the new "Quicker Notifications" settings in chat preferences. When I don't ignore anyone it's all good, however when ignoring someone (probably same when ignoring more than one) I get:

> [image]

Browser Chrome 46, Windows 7.

Comment: You seem to be ignoring a rotated flag of Poland. That's pretty harsh.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just needed to add a `clear: both`. ;-) This will be deployed in chat build 340.

Comment: Another bug cleared! ;)